# not able to import js code in a html code and make it document.write something to it

Tags: javascript

html:

```
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
<!--<script src="h.js"></script>-->
<input id="input" type="text" />
<button id="button">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
//document.open(h.html)
document.write("yo")
const inputNode = document.getElementById('input');
const buttonNode = document.getElementById('button');

buttonNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const inputValue = inputNode.value;

document.write("hi")
});
```

so neither "yo" nor "hi" is being shown on the screen; what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well, the script part in your html is commented out, so of course it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to uncomment the `<script>` tag so that the script is linked properly, you should see "yo" with the input and the button elements.

Then, put the `<script>` tag after the the button, otherwise, the script will execute before the button is created, and therefore the event listener will not be added. Now, when you click the button you should see "hi".

```
<html>
<header>
  <title>This is title</title>
</header>

<body>
  <input id="input" type="text" />
  <button id="button">Click</button>

  <script src="h.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```